# SQLlite in android SUM select not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanna get the sum of `KEY_REC_VAL` from table `MMDatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORD`. My code is resulting in fatal error and I have no idea how to solve it. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
public Integer getIncomesSum()
{
    String col = MMDatabaseHelper.TABLE_RECORD+"."+MMDatabaseHelper.KEY_REC_VAL;
    String whereClause = " WHERE " +TABLE_RECORD+"."+KEY_REC_VAL+" >"+" 0";
    String query = "SELECT sum ("+col+
                   ") FROM "+TABLE_RECORD+
                   whereClause;
    Log.i("SQL",query);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

    } finally {

    } return cursor.getInt(0);
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Answer (score 2):

before return statement add  this line `cursor=cursor.moveToFirst();`